# How to upload files (eg. text/xml) from Windows Phone to remote php server using 'POST'?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

[This](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14021669/RestSharpFileUploadSample.zip) code is not working and returns 'not found' error.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for security reasons I'm not downloading a ZIP from dropbox (corporate network). Can you include the relevant code in your question?

Comment: @AlastairPitts thanks for your consideration, [this](http://nediml.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/uploading-files-to-remote-server-with-multiple-parameters/) is the code, but it is showing not found error for localhost.
I shall be greatly thankful if I find solution for uploading xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.dot4pro.com/posting-data-to-the-web-from-windows-phone-7.html) saved my day. Hope will do the same for you.